# How to get element nested inside multiple divs using a single css selector?

Tags: html, css

This might be a simple question but I can't get it working yet. Below is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="charge-items-page-title">
                <h1 class="page-title">Service Charges Detail</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is, get the `innerHtml` of `h1` using a single selector. I have tried below **css selector** so far, but none worked.

```
browserDriver.GetElement(".charge-items-page-title .page-title")
browserDriver.GetElement("div.charge-items-page-title > h1")
```

I can get this done by adding an `id` to `h1` but I wanted to know what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: some reason `h1.page-title` doesn't work?

Comment: @Scott I just tried your suggestion, but still getting null element

Comment: The I suspect `browserDriver.GetElement()` is the issue.

Comment: which library does this API belong to `browserDriver`? #curious

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am writing automated UI tests using Selenium and Coypu. BrowserDriver is a wrapper to access HTML elements inside browser window. However, I get this working with below css selector: `".modal-header .charge-items-page-title .page-title"`    Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @V.P.Verma Try using a good IDE, for example Cloud9 offers free use, and it will offer intelliSense/auto complete so when you type div.get it will show you the several methods to get at elements by class, tag, id, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but both code examples you gave should work. You can see a demo below. I made your first code set the font color to red and your second code set the background color to yellow.

```css
.charge-items-page-title .page-title {
  color: red;
}
div.charge-items-page-title > h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="charge-items-page-title">
        <h1 class="page-title">Service Charges Detail</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I expected those to work too, but for some reason, they are not working

Comment: What do you mean by "they are not working"? They are working in my demo, aren't they?

Comment: yes, your demo is working. What I meant is the same css selectors are not working in my code.

Comment: But what is `browserDriver.GetElement()` in your code? The issue is there, not with CSS. You need to edit your question and add details about the `browserDriver.GetElement()` so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  `getElementsByTagName` applied to the outer `div`.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-header')[0];
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

function print(){
  alert(y.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
.modal-header{
  display:none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="charge-items-page-title">
                <h1 class="page-title">Service Charges Detail</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="print()">Test</button>
```